# Morphia/MongoDB: can't do getmore

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm trying to iterate over all rows ("documents"?) in my MongoDB database using Morphia. Occasionally I get the following stacktrace:

```
com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: can't do getmore
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$Result._advance(DBApiLayer.java:378)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$Result.hasNext(DBApiLayer.java:356)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:436)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:456)
    at com.google.code.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.hasNext(MorphiaIterator.java:40)
    at
```

In the MongoDB log file I see the following:

```
$ grep "cursorid not found" output.log 
Sun Feb  6 12:14:35 [conn13] getMore: cursorid not found App 2079575931792020691
Sun Feb  6 12:44:17 [conn19] getMore: cursorid not found App 8364953818630631317
Sun Feb  6 13:08:42 [conn20] getMore: cursorid not found App 7142256996888968009
```

My code for iterating is pretty straightforward:

```
    for (App app : datastore.createQuery(App.class).fetch())
    {
        log.info("app: " + app.getId());
        // do stuff with app
    }
```

Morphia bug?  MongoDB bug?  My bug?

**Update:**

I'm also seeing this in my glassfish logs:

```
[#|2011-02-16T15:39:58.029+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.0.1|com.mongodb.TRACE|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|The log message is null.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer._cleanCursors(DBApiLayer.java:113)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$DBCleanerThread.run(DBApiLayer.java:494)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran into the same problem while iterating through a very large Query.  I found this Morphia bug, reported on Mar 21, 2011:

http://code.google.com/p/morphia/issues/detail?id=251

> Issue 251:    enable/disable timeout does the opposite of what it says

The issue says it will be fixed in version 1.0.  The new API `disableCursorTimeout()` is exposed in 1.00-SNAPHSHOT.  I'm running a *long* test to see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/88246dffd68dd117/8efb39c093e5c60e?show_docid=8efb39c093e5c60e) MongoDB releases cursor after a certain amount of time. A possible solution might be to do emulate batch iteration and renew the cursor at the and of the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Is that the actual code? It seems very unlikely that that code would produce that exception. Cursors timeout after 10 minutes of inactivity. With a tight loop like that it seems impossible.

You can use `datastore.createQuery(App.class).disableTimeout()...` to disable the cursor timeout in Morphia. You can also use `datastore.createQuery(App.class).fetchEmptyEntities()` if you just want the `@Id` field filled in.

Also, there is no need to explicitly call `fetch()` if you just want to use the iterator in a for-loop like that; fetch is just needed when you want to store the iterator in a variable and use it in multiple places, but not in a single for-loop.

Comment: I tried to simplify the code as much as possible when asking my question, so you're correct that I've left out potentially useful information. What happens in "do stuff with app" is: query a web service and save results to a file on disk. This typically executes in milliseconds, but I will add some time checks to the loop and see if there isn't some anomalous behavior there that's causing the timeout.  Thanks.

Comment: Just did a few rounds of testing, and learned that the timeout is happening 45 minutes into the iteration process, and this is repeatable. Note that each pass through my iteration loop is typically < 1 second, so it seems to be a timeout on the overall iteration process, and not the delay between each call to Iterator.next().

Comment: It isn't quite that simple. The cursor, iterator, is fetching data in batches from the server; each call to next() may, or may not actually (batch sizes can be 200+), have to talk to the server. Have you tried the disableTimeout option?

Comment: disableTimeout() seems to be working. Is there something special I need to do to release the iterator after I'm done with it, now that the timeout is disabled?

Comment: scratch that- it's STILL failing, even with disableTimeout.